# Virtual box how to set up without user and what is the use of domain name?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am installing windows 10 on my virtualbox and I wonder how I set my user without a password, as I am able to do that on normal host installation but no vm, as it leaves the next button blinded.

I have two questions

**1.** How do I create windows without a password?

[image: VBOX]

**2.** What is the domain name server used for ? Is it something that virtual box uses for its purposes or is it something to do inside windows? If so can I reach the virtualbox at `myguest.virtualbox.org` for example? Can you give any example of its use?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please see [VBOX unattended install](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/virtualbox-unattended-installation-feature/)

Domain is for Windows 10 on a server and not needed if no server.

There is no way I can see of skirting around the password - Normal and good idea in any event.

If you must have a Windows 10 VM without a password, then do not use the unattended install. Download the Windows 10 ISO (Media Creation Link) and install manually. This is not hard to do.